# Is it ok to store SEO relevant content in a database

Tags: zend-framework, seo

I'm building a website in the Zend Framework, and I'm using a layout page that gets applied to all of my pages. It's general structure is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Content of individual pages comes in here...
</body>
</html>
```

Ideally I would like to put `<title>` and `<meta name="description">` etc in this zend layout page, and then pull the content of these tags from my database dynamically depending on which page the content was coming from. Unfortunately, while google is happy to give me TONS of info on how to write title/description/etc tags, I haven't been able to confirm if pulling them from a database is ok. Is it? Am I thinking about this wrong? I'm worried crawlers won't be able to get this content. Is there a better way to associate titles, descriptions, etc with pages (other than just writing a head section in each individual page that contains this info)?

Thanks for the help! (I suspect this is a simple question, but I'd like to confirm the answer somewhere!)

Comment: Yes you can read from the database to populate your title/description info. Google can read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is OK to store titles and meta descriptions in a database.

It is not generally possible for a web browser or a web crawler to even tell whether information is stored on the server in a database, or whether it comes from static files.  Google won't even *know* for sure that your titles and meta descriptions are stored in a database.

Pretty much every CMS system such as WordPress and Drupal store all the content (including titles and meta descriptions) in a database.  It is very common practice.

Comment: Thanks! I assumed it had to be common practice, but couldn't find anything that actually confirmed it!

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your question is **yes, you can store metadata in database**.

Storing metadata in database doesn't affect whether Google crawlers will or will not crawl your pages successfully. As long as you write `<title>` and `<meta>` elements correctly with the info from the database on your pages you'll have no problems.